# How to configure 2 subnets on same LAN and communicate between devices

Tags: networking, router, lan

My setup is I have my primary cable modem/router at one end of the house with IP 192.168.0.1/25. Then I have a secondary router at the other end of the house with IP 192.168.0.129/25. The WAN port of the secondary router is connected to a LAN ports on the primary router. Both routers have a variety of devices connected to them via WiFi and ethernet, all of which have no trouble connected to the internet; the issue is getting them to connect to each other. Currently, each device can only "see" others connected to the same router.

My question is, how do I get these devices to behave as if they were on the same LAN? The functionally I am looking for is being able to print/chromecast/fileshare to/from any devices connected to either router.

I suspect I need to set up port forwarding or something on one or both of the routers, but I'm not sure the correct way to configure this.

Comment: Do you rally *want* two separate networks? Chromecast won’t work across subnets.

Comment: What's the alternative? I've tried running the second router in bridging mode, but whenever I do that devices connected to it lose internet connectivity after 10-15 minutes.

Comment: The alternative is bridged (“AP”) mode. In short: Change AP router’s IP address so it does not conflict, disable DHCP on AP router, connect LAN to LAN. If that causes connection issues, the AP router isn’t working correctly.

Comment: If I put the AP into bridge mode then I can't change it's IP address.

Comment: You don’t need to change the mode. A WiFi router is always bridged between LAN and WiFi.

Comment: I can disable DHCP, but what about NAT? I have two options for that, either "NAT - IPv4 Only" or "NAT - Disable (Bridge Mode)".

Answer (score 1):

Since you apparently don’t really require the separation into two networks, your goal should be to undo that. It’s great that both routers are connected using Ethernet!

Stuff that relies on broadcast or local multicast like Chromecast cannot work across network boundaries, even without NAT.

You indicate your second router causes connection issues when using the “official” bridged mode. Using the following guide, you won’t have to use it:

1. Disconnect the second router
2. Reset it (just be sure)
3. Change its IP address to 192.168.0.2 (or some other free address in the 192.168.0.0/24 network)
4. Set up the WiFi network as desired (probably the same as your other router to allow roaming)
5. Disable DHCP
6. Connect a *LAN* port of your second router to a LAN port of the primary router

And that’s it! *All* other setup on your second router is irrelevant.

You should also change your primary router back to a regular /24 subnet configuration.

You will then have a single network and all services will work as expected. If your second router works fine now it will continue to work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the routers gateway/routing table you can add corresponding entries in your routing table.

on this router
192.168.0.1/25
add
192.168.0.129/25

and vice versa.

in linux

```
ip route add 192.168.0.1/25 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

Windows

route ADD destination_network MASK subnet_mask  gateway_ip metric_cost

```
route ADD 192.168.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.128 192.168.0.129
```

Comment: So does this have to be done individually for every machine on the network?

Comment: The best place is on your routers, however your routers may or may not allow this type of config.  Worst case scenario you may have to buy a 3rd router and put dd-wrt, open wrt or etc on it.

Comment: What sort of setting would this fall under on the router? DMZ? Port forwarding?

Comment: routing or maybe gateway